# How do I keep a count while in a loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dataset that I'm transforming into another array so that it may be processed in a chart. I hvae the chart working, but the `count` key is incorrect. This is what it looks like:

```
export type ChartData = {
  category?: string;
  value?: number | string;
  count?: number;
  createdAt: string;
  physicalActivity?: number;
};


const moodArr: ChartData[] = [];
    if (data) {
      data.assessments.data.forEach((assessment) => {
        const { responses } = assessment.questionnaires[0];
        responses.forEach((response) => {
          response.value.forEach((moodValue) => {
            console.log(moodValue)
            moodArr.push({
              value: toMoodMap(moodValue),
              count: (moodValue || 0) + 1,
              createdAt: moment(assessment.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            })
          });
        });
      });
```

`count` doesn't work because `moodValue` will return as an integer. `toMoodMap` will only map to a String depending on the `moodValue`. However, `count` will just take its original value (which will be 0 - 4) instead of keeping a count of the times its returned. Is there any way to keep a count for this?

Comment: Why not just use a variable outside the function to track the total count?

Comment: does `responses.length` give you the count?

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` takes a second parameter which is the index of the item, so if you just want the count of how many times and item is pushed to the array you could do something like

```
const moodArr: ChartData[] = [];
    if (data) {
      data.assessments.data.forEach((assessment) => {
        const { responses } = assessment.questionnaires[0];
        responses.forEach((response,i) => {
          response.value.forEach((moodValue,j) => {
            console.log(moodValue)
            moodArr.push({
              value: toMoodMap(moodValue),
              count: response.value.length*i + j,
              createdAt: moment(assessment.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            })
          });
        });
      });
```